# amortized analysis accounting method

Tags: amortized-analysis

If you have a dynamic array where the size $s$ becomes $4s$ when you fill the array and there are no delete operations. How much do you spend per insert?

I am asking because when the size doubles, you only spend 3 dollars per insert (based on [this](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/lecture-13-amortized-algorithms-table-doubling-potential-method/lec13.pdf) analysis). But when you make the size 4 times bigger, then for some of the inserts you would need to spend 3\$ and for the rest you spend 2$?

Is this right? Or do we always need to spend the same amount? And if there is extra we just store it in the bank?

Comment: How much you spend depends on you. I wish they'd teach amortized analysis without mentioning money. The idea is that although each operation could be $\Omega(f(n))$, if you run $n$ operations then it total the time is $O(ng(n))$, where $g(n) = o(f(n))$. Charging is just a proof method, and it uses monetary transfers only because it was invented in the US.

Comment: Perform the analysis as mentioned here: http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/10448/4975